# Is there a way to send app request to Facebook friends without the app request dialog?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am creating an app that is connected to Facebook.

One functionality of this app is to send notifications to Facebook friends (they will able to see using any browser when they log in to Facebook, or in Facebook app) to try and download the app.

I was able to create a table list of Facebook friends who don't have the app. And in each UITableViewCell, I added a UIButton titled "Invite" that will call an function to invite that particular friend in the cell.

I want that when the user tapped the button, the Facebook SDK will send a notification to that Facebook friend.

I don't want to use the default app request dialog the Facebook SDK has. I want to customise my own.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible what you are looking for.. See my below answer which would clarify you..

There is option of `frictionless requests`.
On Facebook developer site they mentioned in section of `Invites and Requests`

> We touched on a scenario where users exchange requests back and forth. If this scenario is typical in your game, it can be a bad user experience to force them through the request dialog every time they want to send a request. The solution for this is frictionless requests.
>   Frictionless requests let users send requests to friends from an app without having to click on a pop-up confirmation dialog. When sending a request to a friend, a user can authorize the app to send subsequent requests to the same friend without another dialog. This streamlines the process of sharing with friends.

For more reference see [Facebook Invites and Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-games/requests/)